# how to check if a string contain a seri of letter in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an input, which is a word. 
if my input contains `python`, print `True`. if not, print `False`.
for example: 
if the input is `puytrmhqoln` print `True`(because it contains python's letter, however, there is some letter between `python`)
if the input is `pythno` print `False` (because in types o after n)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your latest attempts so we have a **[mcve]**. Currently, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
import sys
inputs = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
word = "python"
for i in range(len(inputs)):
    if word == "": break
    if inputs[i] == word[0]:
        word = word[1:]
if word == "":
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

it works for words like `hello` with double letter, also `python`

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over each character of your string. And see whether the current character is identical to the currently next one in your string you are looking for:

```
strg = "pythrno"
lookfor = "python"
longest_substr = ""
index = 0
max_index = len(lookfor)
for c in strg:
    if c == lookfor[index] and index < max_index:
        longest_substr += c
        index += 1
print(longest_substr)
```

will give you

```
pytho
```

You now can simply compare `longest_substr` and `lookfor` and wrap this in a dedicated function.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this code will be useful:

Variant 1 (looks for the whole word):

```
s_word = 'python'
def check(word):
    filtered_word = "".join(filter(lambda x: x in tuple(s_word), tuple(word)))
    return filtered_word == s_word

print(check('puytrmhqoln'))
# returns True
print(check('pythno'))
# returns False
```

Variant 2 (seeking character by character, validates the order of the characters):

```
s_word = 'python'
def check(word):
    for i in s_word:
        pre_sym = s_word[s_word.index(i) - 1] if s_word.index(i) > 0 else i
        if word.index(i) < word.index(pre_sym):
            return False
    return True


print(check('pyttthorne'))
# returns True
print(check('puytrmhqoln'))
# returns True
print(check('pythno'))
# returns False
```

Variant 3 (seeking character by character):

```
def check(word):
    w_slice = word
    for c in s_word:
        if w_slice.find(c) < 0:
            return False
        w_slice = word[word.index(c) + 1:]
    return True


s_word = 'hello'
print(check('helo'))
# returns False
print(check('helolo'))
# returns True

s_word = 'python'
print(check('pyttthorne'))
# returns True
print(check('puytrmhqoln'))
# returns True
print(check('pythno'))
# returns False
```

Variant 4 (with regexp):

```
import re
s_word = _REFERENCE_WORD_
# convert the reference word to a regular expression
re_expr = re.compile(r'.*%s{1}.*' % '{1}.*'.join(s_word))
```

Usage:

```
print(True if re_expr.match(_ENTERED_WORD_) else False)
```

Example for 'hello':

```
s_word = 'hello'
re_expr = re.compile(r'.*%s{1}.*' % '{1}.*'.join(s_word))
for w in ('helo', 'helolo', 'hlelo', 'ahhellllloou'):
    print(f'{s_word} in {w} -> {True if re_expr.match(w) else False}')
# returns:
# hello in helo -> False
# hello in helolo -> True
# hello in hlelo -> False
# hello in ahhellllloou -> True
```

Example for 'python':

```
s_word = 'python'
re_expr = re.compile(r'.*%s{1}.*' % '{1}.*'.join(s_word))
for w in ('pyttthorne', 'puytrmhqoln', 'pythno'):
    print(f'{s_word} in {w} -> {True if re_expr.match(w) else False}')
# returns:
# python in pyttthorne -> True
# python in puytrmhqoln -> True
# python in pythno -> False
```

Comment: thank you Andrey, 
this code gives me `False` for `pyttthorne` while `pyttthorne` contains all `python` letters in the right order.

Comment: Adjusted the script, according to the comments. Now `pyttthorne` returns `True`

Comment: But this `def` does not work for words like `hello`.  If  `s_word= 'hello'` that `print(check('helo'))` returens `True'.  But the result should be `False`

Comment: I correctly understand, it is necessary to find all letters of the word in the same quantity? I. e. for the word `hello` there should be one letter `h`, `e`, `o` and 2 letters `l`?

Comment: And here is the third variant :o)

Comment: thanks again Andrey, The letters should be put together.
for example, the answer to `hlelo`  should be `False`. I have to mention that the 3rd edition does not work for a long string like `ahhellllloou`